# jQuery toggleClass & toggle effect responding differently to double-click events, leaving them out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css

I've written a simple accordion-style navigation sidebar (several lists of nav options):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="section">
      <h2>Section 1 Header</h2>
      <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>First Option</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Second Option</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Third Option</li></a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="section">
      <h2>Section 2 Header</h2>
      <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>First Option</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Second Option</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Third Option</li></a>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ...
</nav>
```

jQuery script that hides/reveals lists of nav options when a given section's h2 is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.section ul').hide();
    $('li.section h2').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle('blind', { direction: 'vertical' });
    });
});
```

The whole effect works fine, but I'm running into trouble with double-clicks.

The animation of the accordion effect is handled by the script above--but the "highlight" color of the activated header area is handled with a simple CSS3 transition, which takes effect when the class is toggled by the script.

When I double-click the h2, my toggle blind animation fires only once (which I like), but the toggleClass happens twice (so I'm switched quickly into and out of the 'active' state--leaving it out of sync with the state of the blind animation).

**Is there a way to ignore the second click of a double-click so this toggle only happens once per toggle animation?**

Or maybe it's better to think of it as ignoring a given section's h2 click events while the toggle blind animation is happening on that section...?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the header area "active" after toggle completion. I have not tested, just make a try.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li.section ul').hide();
  $('li.section h2').click(function() {
    var thiz = $(this);
    thiz.parent().children('ul').toggle('blind', { direction: 'vertical' }, function() {
      // make it active after toggle
      thiz.toggleClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe..

```
....
$('li.section h2').bind('click dblclick',function() {
....
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('li.section ul').hide();

  $('li.section h2').click(function() {
    $t = $(this); /* Aliased for ease of use */
    if( !$t.hasClass('active') ){
      /* Not marked as Active yet */
      $('li.section h2.active')
        .not($t)
        .removeClass('active')
          .parent().children('ul')
            .toggle('blind', { direction: 'vertical' });;
      /* Above assumes you want only one h2 to be active at a time.
         If not, remove the above two lines... */
      $t
        .toggleClass('active')
        .parent().children('ul')
          .toggle('blind', { direction: 'vertical' });
    }else{
      /* Already Active! Do Nothing!! */
    }
  });
});
```